# HTTP Keep-Alive to a different Host

Tags: http, keep-alive

If a webserver serves multiple virtual hosts (which can be selected by the client in the HTTP request header *Host*) and supports *Keep-Alive*, is the client allowed to send subsequent requests over the same connection with a different *Host* header?

Comment: It seems yes for Apache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532480/is-http-keep-alive-effective-with-different-domain-on-the-same-webserver

Comment: Also, @Michael Neale reports that connection is reused for different virtual hosts, on Chrome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139379/http-keep-alive-in-the-modern-age

Comment: @shaochuancs: Thank you for the comments! If you copy them to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From performance/efficiency point of view, both browser and server should *Keep-Alive* base on IP, not Hostname. Anyway, the reused connection is on TCP level, not HTTP level.

Although no information is found in [RFC2068](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt)'s Persistent Connections section. It seems Apache *Keep-Alive* between different virtual hosts ([Is http keep-alive effective with different domain on the same webserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532480/is-http-keep-alive-effective-with-different-domain-on-the-same-webserver)). Also, @Michael Neale [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139379/http-keep-alive-in-the-modern-age) that connection is reused for different virtual hosts, on Chrome.